# How to prevent Mazemap from translating custom div outside of canvas?

Tags: leaflet

I'm looking to add custom images to a Mazemap map which I've embedded in my website.
So far I've followed this example: https://api.mazemap.com/js/v2.0.106/docs/#ex-facility-inventory-status

I have copy pasted the CSS-classes and ensured by DOM-structure is equivalent (although I get there in a slightly different way by using React createRoot() and render()).

The issue is: the image does not seem to be fixed to a specific coordinate in the map, so the logo changes physical position when zooming or rotating:

[image: 1st image, logo on left side of the road]

The result of rotating slightly to the right:
[image: 2nd image, logo on the right side of the road]

The image now appears on the other side of the road.

[image: Zooming out makes the image overflow below the canvas]

The result of zooming out. The image overflows below the map canvas.

The purple dot is added at the same coordinates as the image is, but the div around the image is automatically given extra transform: translate styling when rendered, causing it to expand past the canvas.
[image: HTML structure of custom div]

This is the complete code for the component:

```
const Map = ({
longitude,
latitude,
zoomLevel: zoomLevel,
floorLevel: floorLevel,
}: MapProps) => {
const map = useRef<null>(null)

const geojson = {
  type: "FeatureCollection",
  features: [
    {
      type: "Feature",
      geometry: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [longitude, latitude],
      },
      properties: {
        zLevel: -1,
        statusMapText: "Test",
        iconUrl:
        "https://d1csarkz8obe9u.cloudfront.net/posterpreviews/testing-logo-design-template-ce84480d61b3db9a8e1522a99875832f_screen.jpg?ts=1615794516",
      },
    },
  ],
}


return (
  <>
    <Link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://api.mazemap.com/js/v2.0.103/mazemap.min.css"
    />
    <Script
      strategy="afterInteractive"
      src="https://api.mazemap.com/js/v2.0.103/mazemap.min.js"
      onLoad={() => {
      map.current = new window.Mazemap.Map({
        container: "mazemap-container",
        center: { lng: longitude, lat: latitude },
        zoom: zoomLevel,
        zLevel: floorLevel,
        zLevelControl: false,
      })

      const addLogoToMap = (feature) => {
        const mazemapContainer = document.getElementById(
          "mazemap-feature-root"
        )
        const reactRoot = createRoot(mazemapContainer)
        reactRoot.render(
          <>
            <img
              className="inventory-status-icon"
              width="30"
              src={feature.properties.iconUrl}
            />
            <div className="inventory-status-text">
              {feature.properties.statusMapText}
            </div>
          </>
        )

        new Mazemap.ZLevelMarker(mazemapContainer, {
          zLevel: feature.properties.zLevel,
          offZOpacity: 0,
        })
          .setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
          .addTo(map.current)
      }

      map.current.on("load", () => {
        // Add logo
        addLogoToMap(geojson.features[0])
        // Location dot
        const blueDot = new Mazemap.BlueDot({
          map: map.current,
        })
          .setLngLat({ lng: longitude - 0.0005, lat: latitude })
          .setZLevel(-1)
          .setAccuracy(10)
          .show()

        blueDot
          .showBearingHint()
          .setBearingAccuracy(90)
          .setBearing(45)
          .show()

        // Purple dot
        map.current.addSource("geojsonMarkers", {
          type: "geojson",
          data: geojson,
        })
        map.current.addLayer({
          id: "geojsonMarkers",
          type: "circle",
          source: "geojsonMarkers",
          paint: {
            "circle-color": "#ef02aa",
            "circle-radius": 2,
            "circle-stroke-width": 3,
            "circle-stroke-color": "#ef02aa",
          },
          filter: ["==", "zLevel", -1], // Optional - filter features based on a property
        })
        map.current.getSource("geojsonMarkers").setData(geojson)

        // Z-level control
        const customZLevelControl = new window.Mazemap.ZLevelBarControl({
          className: "custom-zlevel-bar static",
          autoUpdate: false,
          zLevels: { "-1": "U1", "-2": "U2" },
        })

        map.current.addControl(customZLevelControl, "bottom-left")
      })
    }}
  />
  <div id="mazemap-container" className="mx-auto h-[70vh] w-[80vw]">
    <div id="mazemap-feature-root" className="custom-alert-marker"></div>
  </div>
</>
```

)
}

Mazemap is not an existing tag in stackoverflow, and I don't have enough rep to create it :(

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure where the source of the incorrect translation is, but in my case it turned out to be exactly equal to the height of the canvas + the height of the icon.
My current best solution is to add an offset equal to that sum in the ZLevelMarker-constructor, as such:

```
new Mazemap.ZLevelMarker(featureRoot, {
          zLevel: feature.properties.zLevel,
          offZOpacity: 0,
          offset: [
            0,
            -1 *
              document.getElementById("mazemap-container")?.offsetHeight -
              feature.properties.height,
          ],
        })
        .setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
        .addTo(map.current)
```